# Windows PDF viewer that can rename file with it open

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a Windows PDF viewer that allows you to rename a file while it is being viewed.

The software can technically be a PDF viewer or editor; it doesn't matter.  All that is important is that it can quickly view a PDF file and allow me to rename it while it is still open.

I've tried the otherwise-excellent [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads), but it does not currently have this functionality.

I prefer gratis, portable, open-source software, but none are requirements.

The cost must be less than about 10 euros/dollars.

Comment: I have yet to come across a PDF reader that will not allow you to use Save As.

Comment: PDF X-Change Editor can now do this

Answer (score 3):

[Sumatra PDF reader](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/) appears to have that ability, though I can't find it mentioned in the docs.  Open a pdf, hit F2, and a file dialog opens up.  Type in the new name and it gets renamed.